# How do you find the formula for a tangent line if there are no points?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, derivatives, tangent-line

The question asks what is the function for the tangent line $b(x)$ if

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{x}}{e^{x}+1}$$

and the part that gets me is the point given is $P = (a,f(a))$.

I derived the gradient and used the slope point formula and subbed it in but to no avail.

Any hints?

here is the work so far ill shorten some of it:

Point slope formula $y-f(a) = m(x-a)$

$m = \frac{e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}$              (first derivative of f(x))

$y-f(a) = \frac{e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}(x-a)$

$y = \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}+\frac{e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}(x-a)$

this is where I am stuck for $(x-a)$ if I sub it in it's wrong so is $a =f(x)$ like $y$?

Comment: It sounds as if you were working correctly; show us your work and we can figure out how to help you.

Comment: You mention "gradient" yet your functions are all of one variable.  Is there some function that is supposed to be of multiple variables?

Comment: For a function of one variable, x, the "gradient" is df/dx.

Comment: added the working so far minus the failed attempts but I know where the issue starts

Answer (score 2):

You just made a slight error there, you put in $f(x)$ instead of $f(a)$, $f(a) = \frac{e^a}{e^a +1}$

So $b(x) = \frac{e^a}{(e^a +1)^2} (x-a)+  \frac{e^a}{e^a +1}$

Comment: how would (x-a) distribute? (also good catch)

Answer (score 0):

You say "there are no points" but (a,f(a)) **is** a point! If $f(x)= \frac{e^x}{e^x+ 1}$ then $f'(x)= \frac{e^x(e^x+ 1)- e^{2x}}{(e^x+ 1)^3}= \frac{1}{e^{2x}+ 2e^x+ 1}$.  At x= a that is $\frac{1}{e^{2a}+ e^a+ 1}$.  Of course, $f(a)= \frac{e^a}{e^a+ 1}$ so the tangent line at (a,f(a)) is

$y= \frac{1}{e^{2a}+ 2e^a+ 1}(x- a)+ a\frac{e^a}{e^a+ 1}$

Comment: how did you get f'(x) as that derivative from the given f(x)?

Comment: The quotient rule: $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'= \frac{f'g- fg'}{g^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series of 1st order

$$ b(x) = f(a) + (x-a) \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} f(x) $$